# failed assertion the relevant error-causing widget was textformfield

Tags: ios, flutter

Working on a flutter project and the code is stable on android every thing just working fine but when I want to debug at ios I am getting below errors. Could not understand why it is happing.

Any idea would help.

```
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building UnmanagedRestorationScope:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was
TextFormField
lib/…/login/loginPage.dart:63
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack


════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4531 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4531
The relevant error-causing widget was
TextFormField
```

and the error point it out to loginPage widget is

```
   Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: viewModel.usernameText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: const Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
              color: qPrimaryColor,
            ),
            hintText: PageTextConst.username,
            labelText: PageTextConst.username,
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
        validator: (String? text) {
          if (text!.isEmpty) {
            return PageTextConst.enterUsername;
          } else if (text.length < 6) {
            return PageTextConst.falseUsername;
          } else {
            return "";
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
```

**EDIT :**
TextFormField controller

```
class LoginAuthViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  String versionName = "";

  TextEditingController usernameText = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordText = TextEditingController();
```

Comment: try removing the return ""; inside else{} and put return null; instead inside else{}

Comment: @LearnFlutter tried and still same error thrown. and also removed TextFormFiled validator and nothing changed.

Comment: can you show the viewModel.usernameText, how did you declare it

Comment: @LearnFlutter I have added them at post

Answer (score 0):

```
 Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
  child: SizedBox(
   height:50,
   width:100,
        child: TextFormField(
    controller: viewModel.usernameText,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(
          Icons.account_circle,
          color: qPrimaryColor,
        ),
        hintText: PageTextConst.username,
        labelText: PageTextConst.username,
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
    validator: (String? text) {
      if (text!.isEmpty) {
        return PageTextConst.enterUsername;
      } else if (text.length < 6) {
        return PageTextConst.falseUsername;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    },
  ),
),)
```

Simply add the sized box around the textformfield

Comment: If you have any question feel free to ask me.